Get the spark jobName using Databricks all-purpose cluster
I am building system that collect data from various of remote system to a central spark cluster. I am saving the local data using Delta format.
After the collection, I want to get the number of collected rows from the Delta's log.
I am using this piece of code:
def __get_job_name(self) -> str:
    all_cluster_tags = {}
    for tag in json.loads(
        self.spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.clusterAllTags")
    ):
        all_cluster_tags[tag["key"]] = tag["value"]

    return all_cluster_tags.get("RunName")

def __extract_delta_operation_data(self) -> tuple[int, int]:
    delta_table = DeltaTable.forPath(self.spark, self.target_table_path)
    history_df = delta_table.history()
    count, bytes_size = 0, 0

    if not is_local_spark():
        curr_job_name = self.__get_job_name()

        relevant_op_data_row = (
            history_df.filter(history_df["job"]["jobName"] == curr_job_name)
            .filter(history_df["operation"].isin(["STREAMING UPDATE", "WRITE"]))
            .sort(history_df.timestamp.desc())
            .collect()
        )
        if relevant_op_data_row:
            last_op_data_row = relevant_op_data_row[0]
            operation_metrics = last_op_data_row[12]
            count = operation_metrics.get("numOutputRows", 0)
            bytes_size = operation_metrics.get("numOutputBytes", 0)

    return count, bytes_size

This code works great while running the collection job in a job-cluster.
When I am running this on all-purpose cluster the function returns 0,0 because the function __get_job_name returns None.
Any idea how to extract the jobName from the all-purpose cluster?
I know that this jobName exists for this operation (That executed on all-purpose cluster) because when I am running describe history for this table I am getting the data with a jobName.
Thanks

We solved this issue using parameter that send the value reference to the job.
https://docs.databricks.com/en/workflows/jobs/parameter-value-references.html#supported-value-references
note that there is a bug in Databricks, this should work but it does not:
{{job.id}}
We are using the deprecated value:
{{job_id}}
